# How do i find the variable name for coupon code and coupon value?

Tags: product, coupon

Can anyone tell me how I can include the coupon code and value of the coupon in an Order CSV that gets sent to the order fulfillment company? I am using Magento CE 1.8.1.

Basically when an order is generated, it also generates a CSV file with the order details and uploads this to the order fulfillment company. Looking through the code I can see that it pulls in other order data from variables e.g:

```
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress()->toArray();
    $email = $billingAddress['email'];
    $telephone = $billingAddress['telephone'];
```

What would be the variable name for pulling in the name and value of any money-off coupon that happens to be used for that order? I can't see any way of finding this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting order coupon code used below code

```
$order->getCouponCode();
```

For Coupon description

```
$order->getDiscountDescription();
```

And Also getting order discount Price

```
$DiscountPrice=$order->getDiscountAmount();
```

Comment: I just looked and already have $order in the file that pulls in the order details and sends them to the order fulfilment company. For example I have this in the file already:

Comment: public function processOrderPayed($observer){
  $event = $observer->getEvent();
  $invoice = $event->getInvoice();
  $order = $invoice->getOrder();

Comment: what you  want from me???

Comment: Well I guess what I'm saying is that I already have $order = $invoice->getOrder(); in the code, so will the above lines for getting the coupons work?

Comment: yes . i will working .. if it not work then load $order BY Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($invoice->getOrder()->getId())

Comment: Actually I tested it without changing, just adding 2 new variables for $couponcode and $couponvalue and that all worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$order->getDiscountDescription();`

Comment: I just need one more bit of info pulled through to the order fulfilment company now- that's the actual value of the order (excluding shipping). How can I get this value added in, in the same way as the above?